# Python - Tensorflow Advice on Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

**The project :**
Find out if a breast x-ray contains a benign or malignant tumor with the help of a convolutional neural network.

This is the **link** for the **github repository** :
https://github.com/aubreyDKR/CNNBreastCancer.git

You can see the **project** on the **file** : ImageLearningProject.ipynb
The latest version is on the **branch** : aubrey

**The problem :**
we can see in the part "Evaluate Model" that there is something wrong with the model accuraccy because it doesn't improve with the times. Why ? How to resolve this ?

If other informations are needed. Tell it to me.

---

**Update :**
After some advice I made the next update.

1. Add Batch Normalization layers and Activation layers.
2. Change the loss fonction from . . . to Binary Crossentropy. So the last dense layer was changed from softmax to sigmoid.
3. The file names are no more printed to have a cleaner notebook.

**Results :**
We can see some changes to the model accuracy plot. But always look like something is wrong. I think that the model should be better for each epochs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: I see you deleted the other question, if you undelete it I have a solution for you.

Comment: I'll just post it here, let me know if it works for you https://godbolt.org/z/35jvWcfrj

Comment: @anastaciu oh ok thanks yeah its work, why there is nothing about this in any tutorial that i look ? Maybe because they put the class in a different folder and use a header for that ?

Comment: @AubreyDekker I can't answer that, IDK the tutorial you look in, I also don't know what the problem was about the structure of your program that didn't work without looking at it, a thing that was a big problem was the lack of data member initialization, without that they would all be 0. With time these things will become trivial, trust me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. My first advice is: You should remove the print statement that outputs the file names, it is unnecessary and messes your notebook output space :)
2. Your task is a binary classification task. The label is either 0 (malign) or 1 (benign) or the other way around, it does not matter. However, you are using a wrong loss function categorical cross entropy which is for multi-class classification. You should use BinaryCrossEntropy. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy
3. You can try apply max pooling every second CNN layer
4. Batch normalization might help. In this case, you should remove the activation in the cnn layers and after each convolution you can apply Batch Normalization and after that you should have an activation layer (e.g ReLU)

Comment: I made an update with your advices. I understand all of the concepts and what is happening for the Conv2D and MaxPooling layers. But dont really understand the batch normalisation and the activation layer. I need to read about it.

"You can try apply max pooling every second CNN layer" what do you mean ? Is the update is correct for this ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: I do not see the changes but whatever. In general you normalize in order to avoid your gradients and weights becoming too large. You should also apply normalization to the input but this normalized input can still get magnified during the layers. So, batch normalization also normalizes the outputs between the layers to prevent this. It also has some sort of a regularizing effect. The thing is max pooling is that you basically reduce the dimension of the image by half which is an information loss. It is needed to reduce the complexity but it can also has side effects. You can apply 2 CNN layers

Comment: and then max pooling to reduce the effect of information loss because your learned features would be refined

Comment: Oh ok i see thanks, did you check the file in the branch aubrey ? Not in the main one ?

Comment: yes in the branch aubrey I see them, thanks. Apply the mx pooling after activation layer not in between conv and BN. The rest looks goods